# Вызов метода класса по имени

Tags: c#

Необходимо вызывать методы класса по имени (т.е. мне известна строка с именем метода класса). Нашел только один более менее подходящий способ - использовать рефлексию.

```
public class Simple
{
    public string SimpleMethod(string param1)
    {
        return param1;
    }
}

//и собственно вызов 
Simple simple = new Simple();
var method = typeof(Simple).GetMethod("SimpleMethod");
object[] param = new object[] {"Hello World!"};
string result = method.Invoke(sample, param) as string;
```

Но как я понимаю от такого способа сильно падает производительность. Есть ли более "элегантное решение"?

Comment: еще можно создавать Expression и компилировать его перед вызовом

Comment: Как вам если самому реализовать метод типа делегат в классе Simple, или даже как метод-расширения? Правда нужно заранее знать название всех нужных  методов, и в теле метода типа делегат использовать убогий switch

Comment: @4per интересный вариант, но методы разные по сигнатуре, придется писать под каждый метод по сути свой делегат, если я правильно понял вашу мысль

Comment: @e1s, еще вариант, сложить в словарь методы которые могут вызываться и вызывать из из словаря

Answer (score 2):

Тут предлагают использовать [System.Linq.Expressions](https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2014/05/23/dynamically-call-c-instance-method-by-string-name-without-performance-overhead/):

```
namespace Research.UnitTests
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;

    [TestClass]
    public class Research
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestWithTiming()
        {
            var calculator = new Calculator();           
            //Получить ссылку на метод "Calculate".
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Calculator).GetMethod(
                "Calculate", 
                new Type[] { typeof(int) });

            //Создать параметр.
            ParameterExpression param =  Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");           
            //Создать "точку вызова".
            var thisParameter = Expression.Constant(calculator);
            //Создать выражение для вызова метода.
            //Если бы метод был статический, то "точка вызова" была бы
            //лишней.
            MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
                thisParameter,
                methodInfo, 
                param);
            //Создать лямбда-выражение.
            Expression<Func<int, string>> lambda = 
                Expression.Lambda<Func<int, string>>(
                    methodCall,
                    new ParameterExpression[] { param }
                    );
            //Откомпилировать лямбда-выражение в Func<>.
            Func<int, string> func = lambda.Compile();

            //Замеряем производительность вызова c использованием рефлексии.
            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                string result = (string)methodInfo.Invoke(calculator, new object[] { i });
            }
            watch.Stop();
            System.Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            //Замеряем производительность вызова по имени.
            watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                string result = func(i);
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            //Замеряем производительность прямого вызова.
            watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                string result = calculator.Calculate(i);
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    public class Calculator
    {
        public string Calculate(int i)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            //Референсный код.
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime nextDay = now.AddDays(i);
            result = nextDay.ToString();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

> 1930 (рефлексия)
>
> 1530 (expression)
>
> 1519 (прямой вызов)